# How to speed up MATLAB knnsearch method for a single matrix?

Tags: matlab, knn

I want to use the `knnsearch` method in MATLAB to find nearest node. I have a `2000×200` matrix, each row is a node, which means there are `2000` nodes each have `200` attributes. I want to find each node's nearest node in this matrix (the node itself is not included), but I can't find a efficient way to do this.

Here is my code for this problem which is very slow right now (I used a loop, which makes it very slow, but I can't figure out a better way...):

```
function [N,time] = KNN(X)
tic;
[height,width] = size(X);
N = zeros(height,1);
for i = 1:height
    k = knnsearch(X([1:i-1 i+1:height],:),X(i,:));
    if k<i
        N(i,1) = k;
    else
        N(i,1) = k+1;
    end
end
time = toc;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of your data points overlap, you can try using the 'Distance' option of knnsearch() and define a custom distance function. In this distance function, you can map zero distance to infinity or some other very large number. This gets rid of the need to use a for loop and should speed things up.

If there are overlaps, this trick can still work. You just create a dummy dimension to label the points and include it in the custom distance function.

See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html